# Uncaught TypeError: user.toLowerCase is not a function

Tags: reactjs, search, filter

okay guys so new update. so i did jus that . i moved all the elements to the rendering and tried to just get the state to be alone. when i tried that it told me that map wasnt able to read properties of undefined. so what i did was added the object keys . the page rendered ... kinda. it rendered without all the data. i attached the updated code in here but now im kinda confused because its not showing an error this time .its just not displaying the info. can someone tell me what im doing wrong here ?

Comment: `user` is not a string, it is a `ul` element that you create in the `setInfo(json.students.map())` call in the `useEffect`. `toLowerCase()` only works with strings

Comment: so how would i go about i reaching the needed data and still be readable at the same time ?

Comment: i mean like how could i reach the data and it still be readable to be able to filter through the details ???

Comment: Don't create any DOM elements in your state and leave your `info` as an array of objects. Move the logic for creating the DOM elements to your `return`.

Comment: Also, I would not change your state when you filter as you would not be able to easily get the original, unfiltered state values back. Keep track of your filters in state and do conditional rendering based on the filters in your `return`

Comment: okay i will try that. youre basically saying i cant filter because it cant read the elements. so in order to map or filter i need to bring everything to the return section . in order to manipulate the array better .

Comment: thank you that solved a head ache . youre a live saver. this is my first time here so do i owe you like some sort of points ????

Comment: Welcome and I'm glad you were able to solve your issue. Points are nice but not necessary. In general I think reputation points are only awarded to answers so I copied my above comments to an answer

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you that `user.toLowerCase` is not a function, indicating that `user` is not a string as `toLowerCase` only works with strings. Instead, `user` is the `ul` element you create in the `setInfo(json.students.map())` call in the `useEffect`. It's not ideal to store DOM elements in state for this reason as it's not easy to work with. Instead, leave your `info` state variable as an array of objects, and move the logic for creating DOM elements in your `return`.

In addition, I would not change your state when you filter as you would not be able to easily get the original, unfiltered state values back. Keep track of your filters in state and do conditional rendering based on the filters in your return.

Answer (score 0):

You setting your user info as a ul html list. Instead set the userInfo the json response and then map the ul list when you render the component.

I'm not sure what your user json looks like, so you might have to play around with that.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card";
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import { Input } from "@material-ui/core";

function StudentProfiles()  {

    const [info, setInfo] = useState();
    const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
    
    
    useEffect(() => {
        
         fetch("https://api.hatchways.io/assessment/students")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => setInfo(json))
    },[]);
    
    
    const average = (array) => array.reduce((a,b) => a + b )/ array.length;
    
    const filter = (e) => {
        const keyword = e.target.value;

        if(keyword !== '') {
            const results = info.filter((user) => {
                return user.students.toLowerCase().startsWith(keyword.toLowerCase());
            });
            setInfo(results);

        } else {
            setInfo(info)
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Card className="card">
                <CardContent className="scrollbar scrollbar-primary mt-5 mx-auto">
                    <Input
                    className="searchBar"
                    icon="search"
                    placeholder="Search by name"
                    onChange={filter}
                    />
                { user.students.map((name) => (
                  <ul className = "border" key={name.id}>
                      <Grid item xs={3} sm={6} md={12} style={{display: "flex", gap:"3.5rem", paddingBottom:"8px"}}>
                      <img alt ="" src={name.pic} className="picture"></img> 
                        <Grid  container style={{display: "inline"}} align="left" justify="flex-end" alignItems="flex-start">
                          <Grid  className="studentNames">
                          <span>{name.firstName + " " + name.lastName}</span>
                          </Grid>
                          <span>{name.email}</span>
                          <br/>
                          <span>{name.company}</span>
                          <br/>
                          <span>{name.skill}</span>
                          <br/>
                          <span>Average: {average(name.grades).toFixed(3)}%</span>
                        </Grid>
                      </Grid>
                </ul>
              )))}
                </CardContent>
            </Card>
        </div>
    )
}

export default StudentProfiles;
```

Comment: hey i updated the code do you mind taking a look at it ?

Comment: @stackoverflowrog can you post your new code and the json data so we can see the structure?